# How to compare JavaScript objects obtained by parsing JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

```
wtf1 = JSON.parse('{"asdf": "jkl"}');
wtf2 = JSON.parse('{"asdf": "jkl"}');

wtf1 == wtf2; // false
wtf1 === wtf2; // false
```

I’ve recently stumbled upon the above problem. This counter-intuitive situation makes it hard to, for example, find a specific object in an array deep in a JSON hierarchy.

Any way to somehow compare such objects?

Comment: Why don't you compare them before parsing?

Comment: nope, these objects are different. You need to compare them key by key...

Comment: Just an FYI, `==` and `===` are equivalent when comparing objects, since you're comparing the reference, and not the object itself.

Comment: Trivial solution comparing keys from both objects is very simple and bullet-proof.

Answer (score 7):

For simple objects you can stringify them again (with ordered keys) and compare strings. For example:

```js
var wtf1 = JSON.parse('{"a": "a", "b": "b"}');
var wtf2 = JSON.parse('{"b": "b", "a": "a"}');
var s1 =  JSON.stringify(wtf1, Object.keys(wtf1).sort());
var s2 =  JSON.stringify(wtf2, Object.keys(wtf2).sort());
console.log('wtf1 is equal to wtf2: ', (s1 == s2));
```

For nested objects with prototypes etc you should probably use [_.isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) or any other lib that provides deep equality test.

Note, that in general it's not trivial to correctly implement deep equality test for objects, it's not as simple as iterating and comparing keys/values. However, since the "objects were obtained by parsing JSON" you can skip most of complications and recursively stringify nested values.

Comment: Not reliable. For example what about `'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'` and `'{"b": 2, "a": 1}'`?

Comment: @dfsq addressed

Comment: @Pavel - Your sort does not address nested values.

Comment: This shouldn't even be answered. This question has been asked numerous times already on SO

Comment: Plus this is very weird passing array as second parameter to `JSON.stringify`. Not only it's wrong, but makes it look like it is important to pass it as second argument.

Comment: @dfsq why is it weird? It's an array of keys that you want to be stringified. For simple cases that would be enough IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to just compare them before you parse into objects. But this only works if they are exactly the same, including the order of the properties

```js
var obj1 = {name: "potato", age: 10}
var obj2 = {name: "potato", age: 10}

console.log(obj1 == obj2) //false

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) == JSON.stringify(obj2)) //true

var obj1 = {name: "potato", age: 10}
var obj2 = {age: 10, name: "potato"}

console.log(obj1 == obj2) //false

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) == JSON.stringify(obj2)) //also false
```

Comment: They are in an array, and an array is a property of another object… Overall they’re pretty deep in the JSON hierarchy. I thought I could just `JSON.parse` the whole JSON, and then work on it. This fact makes Your approach a little difficult

Comment: But you have them non-parsed, right? Just compare them. But again: they need to have the same structure/order on the properties. Maybe you could sort the properties before comparing

Comment: If I have the whole JSON parsed, then in particular I have these two objects parsed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare objects ( as theyre differnet ), but you can iterate over each property, and compare them (and recursively check if theyre objects again):

```
function compare(obj1,obj2){
   //check for obj2 overlapping props
   if(!Object.keys(obj2).every(key=>obj1.hasOwnProperty(key))){
      return false;
   }

   //check every key for being same
   return Object.keys(obj1).every(function(key){

      //if object
      if((typeof obj1[key]=="object" )&&( typeof obj2[key]=="object")){

          //recursively check
          return compare(obj1[key],obj2[key]);
      }else{

          //do the normal compare
          return obj1[key]===obj2[key];
      }
   });
}
```

http://jsbin.com/zagecigawi/edit?js

Comment: What if all of obj1's keys are in obj2, but all of obj2's keys are not in obj1?

Comment: @TravisJ then it will fail

Comment: That will work. Although, perhaps you should make sure there aren't key duplication. `key=>{if(!keys.has(key))keys.add(key)}` should work I think

Comment: "keys.every is not a function"

Comment: @mhodges edited... ( am i right that we can simply bind the Set to it?)

Comment: @mhodges this is overcomplexed isnt it? cant one simply do Array.from ?

Comment: @Jonasw I messed up, try this one instead: https://repl.it/IB2z/5 . There is actually no need to create a set, considering object properties are unique already. You can compare the lengths of the key arrays and use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @mhodges yep, just decided to do so. Set wouldve been faster ( i believe ), but then i could not iterate over it that simple...

Comment: @Jonasw - Ah, yes they are unique. Disregard the previous duplication comment please.

Answer (score 1):

you can use loadash for the same.
using _.isEqual("object1", "object2");

```js
var obj1 = {"prop1" : 2, "prop2" : 3 };
var obj2 = {"prop1" : 2, "prop2" : 3};

console.dir(_.isEqual(obj1, obj2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Second approach would be
 JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)

Answer (score 1):

This will compare JSON structure of response and model(It will compare keys only and not values & will work for any hierarchy)

```
function compareObjects(response, model) {

    if (response == "" && model == "") {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof (response) != "object" && typeof (model) != "object") {
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        var model = JSON.parse(model);
    }

    if (typeof (response) != typeof (model)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(model)) {
            case '[object]':
                var x;
                var mKeys = Object.keys(model);
                for (x in mKeys) {
                    return compareObjects(Object.keys(model)[x], Object.keys(response)[x]);
                }
                break;

            case '[object Array]':
                return compareObjects(model[0], response[0]);

            case "[object String]":
                return model == response;

            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
}
var response = '[{"educationId":5,"degreeName":"Bacheltecture - B.Arch"},{"educationId":2,"degreeName":"Bachelor of Arts - B.A. "},{"educationId":3,"degreeName":"Bachelor of Ayurvedic Medicine  Surgery - B.A.M.S. "}]';
var model = '[{"degreeName":null},{"educationId":null,"degreeName":null},{"educationId":null,"degreeName":null}]';

var output = compareObjects(response, model);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two objects in JS even with same properties are never equal. You can stringify objects and compare those strings or iterate over all properties (but it's hard if you need deep compare)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a library implementation for Object equality checking. Try the [lodash version](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual).

```
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };

_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true
```